# Artifactory move/copy artifacts between remote repositories

Tags: api, repository, move, artifactory

for local repositories it works perfectly well.
I use the instruction from https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/is-there-a-way-to-rename-a-repository/

However, when the repos are remote ones, the following errors are showing up:

1) Remote repo names

```
curl -k -X POST -u admin "https://myartifactory/artifactory/api/move/generic-dev?to=/generic-release/
```

Result:

```
"messages" : [ {
    "level" : "ERROR",
    "message" : "Failed to copy from src=generic-dev to target=/generic-release/: Attempt to lock 'generic-dev:' with repository 'generic-dev-cache"
  }, {
    "level" : "WARNING",
    "message" : "Source repository path is empty, path set to root"
```

2) With caches:

```
curl -k -X POST -u admin "https://myartifactory/artifactory/api/move/generic-dev-cache?to=/generic-release-cache/
```

Result:

```
[Error] Artifactory response: 409 Conflict
    {
      "messages": [
        {
          "level": "ERROR",
          "message": "Failed to copy from src=generic-dev-cache/taf to target=generic-release-cache/: Target repository generic-release-cache is a cache repository. copy to cache repositories is not allowed."
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am using  Artifactory Professional 5.4.6

Please help if you know the solution.

Best regards,

Marek

Comment: You cannot deploy a file into a remote repository and so you cannot copy/move from one remote (cache) to another remote (cache). What you can do instead is to copy the remote cache content to a local repository. It might be interresting to ellaborate on your use case as I think the copy to a local is what you are looking for (preserver external pacakes that has been consumed in dev - qualified and are now ready for release).

Comment: a workaround would be to connect the new remote (generic-release) to the cache of the older one (in its configuration page) and then perform a pull replication to fetch all the content and populate the new cache. But again the first approach is what fullfill most of use cases